# pdf created with jspdf won't open in Edge

Tags: reactjs, pdf, microsoft-edge, jspdf

I created a pdf with jspdf and dom-to-image-more. It works great in Chrome and Microsoft Teams, the latest Adobe Illustrator on Creative Cloud handles it fine, but it won't display in Edge. It renders about half then gets stuck.

It's not massive - 4182kb. I've also reset Edge to the default app for pdfs in Windows 10 and done a Repair on Edge. No joy. Even opening in Adobe Illustrator and saving without editing, layers and optimised for fast web display yields no improvement.

I'm not even sure if this is just a Windows 10 bug, but knowing that would help!

My code shows the pdf generation by first converting the DOM to jpeg, then saving that as a pdf. Is this approach flawed? If so could you explain why?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (reportRef.current && advisorSignature.current) {
        let node = reportRef.current;
        let reportHeight = reportRef.current.scrollHeight
        let reportWidth = reportRef.current.offsetWidth
        console.log("REPORT HEIGHT", reportHeight)

        domtoimage.toJpeg(node, {width: reportRef.current.offsetWidth * 2, height: reportRef.current.scrollHeight * 2})
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [reportHeight - 20, reportWidth]);

            pdf.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 0, -12, reportWidth, reportHeight);
            pdf.save("download.pdf"); 
            download(dataUrl, 'my-node.jpg')
        })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });}
}, [reportRef])
```

Any insights appreciated - even if it's a good reason to persuade our clients not to use Edge!

Comment: Can you post a link to the PDF file so we can take a look at it?

Comment: Looks like you are using the MS Edge legacy browser. Can you please inform us which exact version of the Edge browser you are using? Also, inform the OS build. Your code is not giving any idea about the issue. I also made a test with the sample code from the official jsPDF site and it worked fine with the MS Edge legacy browser on my side. If possible try to share the PDF file to check for the issue. Does the Edge browser get hanged? Does it show any error or warning message in the console?